# Is it possible to have a default struct initializer which able to exclude properties with initial value?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following struct.

```
struct Checklist : Codable {
    let id: Int64
    var text: String?
    var checked: Bool
    var visible: Bool = false
    var focused: Focused? = nil
    var version: Int64 = 0

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case text
        case checked
    }
}
```

I wish I can construct it by using

```
var checklist = Checklist(id: 1, text: nil, checked: true)
```

I notice that will cause me compiler error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I need to resolve this, by providing an initializer, explicitly.

```
struct Checklist : Codable {
    let id: Int64
    var text: String?
    var checked: Bool
    var visible: Bool = false
    var focused: Focused? = nil
    var version: Int64 = 0

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case text
        case checked
    }

    init(id: Int64, text: String?, checked: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
        self.checked = checked
    }
}
```

I was wondering, is it ever possible, to have an auto default initializer. It should be able to exclude all properties (`visible`, `focused` and `version`) which have default value?

So that, I need not provide an initializer explicitly. (Less code, need not to maintain our own initializer, less possible mistake)

Comment: That feature was added in Swift 5.1, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586158/struct-memberwise-initialization-omitting-values-for-properties-that-have-defa.

Comment: Wow. Not aware of this. I guess that requires XCode 11, which in turn requires macOS 10.15 Catalina Public Beta ?

Comment: It requires Xcode 11 (beta), but that runs on macOS 10.14.

Comment: Yes. I'm using maxOS 10.14. But, I went to App Store just now, and look for XCode. There are no update to XCode 11 option. Am I missing something?

Comment: Xcode 11 is still in beta, and can be downloaded from http://developer.apple.com/download/. A (free) Apple ID should be sufficient to get access.